# Ajax calling on clicking a button in html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I was learning about Ajax calling and I tried implementing this following code. I have created a button in HTML which on clicking should go to the specified URL that was called using Ajax.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">    
            <p>{{user}}</p>
            </ul>
            <button id="button" onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
            <p></p>

            <script> 
                function test() {
                    var username = "test@liferay.com";
                    var password = "test";

                    function auth(username, password) {
                        var token = username+ ':' + password;
                        var hash = btoa(token);
                        return "Basic" + hash;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://192.166.7.23:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-id/user-id/10198',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("p").text(data);
                        },
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth(username, password));
                        },
                        complete:function() {},
                        error: function(data) {
                            alert(data)
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the call is not happening on clicking the button. 
Kindly tell me where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Nope. I didn't see any error .

Comment: Unless `http://192.168.1.17:8080` matches the calling domain *exactly* (down to the port number) then the response to your request will be blocked by the Same Origin Policy. If this is the case, you should see a warning in the console about it.

Comment: When i tried , i am getting XHR cannot load  http://192.166.7.23:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-id/user-id/10198 .no 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' is present on the requested source.